# Event subscription changed - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, events, action, monogame

UI Elements can subscribe events like press, hold or release. Therefore, I created an object variable to store those information

```
        private Dictionary<TouchListenerType, List<Action<int, float, Vector2>>> touchData = new Dictionary<TouchListenerType, List<Action<int, float, Vector2>>>();
```

Every update cycle I iterate over every provided input and delegate it to the subscribers.

```
        try
        {
            for (int currentTouchIndex = touchCollections.Count - 1; currentTouchIndex >= 0; currentTouchIndex--)
            {
                Vector2 position = MapInput(touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Position);
                if (touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].State == TouchLocationState.Moved &&
                    touchData[TouchListenerType.Move].Count > 0)
                    touchData[TouchListenerType.Move].ForEach(d => d.Invoke(touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Id, touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Pressure, position));
                else if (touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].State == TouchLocationState.Pressed &&
                    touchData[TouchListenerType.Press].Count > 0)
                    touchData[TouchListenerType.Press].ForEach(d => d.Invoke(touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Id, touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Pressure, position));
                else if (touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].State == TouchLocationState.Released &&
                    touchData[TouchListenerType.Release].Count > 0)
                    touchData[TouchListenerType.Release].ForEach(d => d.Invoke(touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Id, touchCollections[currentTouchIndex].Pressure, position));
            }
        } catch { } //Enumeration could have been changed
```

If a subscriber decides to unsubscribe or to add another subscription based on the provided input, the exception **System.InvalidOperationException** will be thrown, because the event subscriber count has been changed. Till now I just put a try-catch around the block. But I would like to avoid the original problem.

Based on the fact that every subscriber is able to unsubscribe/subscribe in the delegate, I can't work with semaphores. Also I would like to avoid to create a copy of the event every update cycle, since this application is running on mobile devices. How am I able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a [Concurrent Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) is sufficient?

You may also need to implement [Custom Event Accessors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx).

Edit:

The error is generated by the `List<T>.ForEach` statement, where the collection is changed during iteration. A `for` loop should be used to allow for this.

Comment: A lock is the equation of a monitor. But maybe I should really use events instead of the actions.

Comment: Are you getting an error during the List<T>.ForEach? Perhaps you should be changing it to a `for` loop so its size can change during iteration.

Comment: Right, on. Good luck!

Comment: @ThomasChristof Edited my answer for visibility.